# How to remove the error while installing python 3 packages in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, python

I always hit by some of the below error while installing any package with the connection with python3. But it works really fine with the python2 packages. 
Following is the error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
cav-linux : Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but it is not installable
 python3-tk : Depends: blt (>= 2.4z-9) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: tk8.6-blt2.5 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

.

Comment: `cav-linux`  and `libssl10.9.8` are not Ubuntu packages.  They are incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. Uninstall them and delete (or disable) whatever source you got them from.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can remove these errors from my PC. I don't really understand what they are?

Comment: Thank you so much.' sudo apt-get -f install ' command solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved using following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This command will remove all the error mentioned above.